# Menu Item - Show only a few articles

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, com-content, layout, category-blog

I have a general question. I want to show for instance four articles ( or ten, the number doesn't matter just so much as I want ) that are in a category "articles". So the problem is that in the category "articles" are more then just four articles but I just want to show four and not all. For instance a preview site where just the newest or the four selected articles are shown and for the other articles I have to click a readmore button where only then ALL articles are listed.

I thought about a sub category but that wouldn't solve the problem I think.

I appreciate every help and comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the featured articles system represented with a star in content manager and use a **"Featured Articles"** menu item type to show only the specific articles that you have marked.

Then use a link to another item menu with the complete list of articles in that category.

**Latest articles**

To show only latest articles you have lot of solutions:

- **Blog layout** item type, under "Blog layout" tab you can customize number of articles, ordering, pagination, etc..
- **Articles - Latest** module that is exactly used to show most recently published articles
- **Articles - Category** module, to display a list of articles from one or more categories
- **Articles - Newsflash** module, to display a fixed number of articles

In all of this tools you have a lot of customizable options to reach your needs. Anyway to provide a link to a complete list of articles I think you have to override the view adding a link to another item menu or create a Custom module with that link.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would that be the only solution that Joomla! provides? For instance I want to show only the newest 3 articles. Would I've to code this with PHP to get this solution or is there another option in Joomla! ?

Comment: See the updated answer for latest articles display

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Nicola's answer, there can be other ways to achieve what you are after.

A very common one, is to display articles using a module. 
You could create an article, where you will load that specific module with the [**loadposition / loadmodule syntax**](https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F), and assign this article to a menu item.

Then this page will display whatever articles you have selected to be displayed by that module.

There are hundreds of modules with different settings, capabilities and layout options. One of my favorites is a commercial one and is called **[RAXO All-mode PRO](http://www.raxo.org)**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer too. I'll check your favorite out!